# Error: The specified value is out of range in C# power point

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I am trying to calibrify the text in entire presentation but if i have some ppt that is  already designed my first slide consists of almost 37 shapees .

so when i calibrify some shapen it gives an error saying " the specified value is out of range"

Below is my code:

```
private void Calibrify_text_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        PowerPoint.SlideRange ppslr = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange;
        int slidecount = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides.Count;

        for(int i = 1; i <= slidecount; i++)
        {
            ppApp.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides.Range(i).Select();
            ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(i).Shapes.SelectAll();
            PowerPoint.ShapeRange ppshr = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange;

            for(int j = 1; j <= ppshr.Count; j++)
            {
                if (ppshr[j].HasTextFrame.ToString() !="")
                {
                    var text = ppshr[i].ToString();

                    if (ppshr[j].TextFrame.TextRange.Text != "")
                    {
                        var text1 = ppshr[j].TextFrame.TextRange;
                        text1.Font.Name = "Calibri Light";
                    }
                }
            } 
        }    
    }
    catch (COMException Ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Some problem" + Ex.Message + Ex.StackTrace);
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload your pptx file to some public location so I could test it, against my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an example for you **assuming** that there are **several files** with **several shapes** on it. Furthermore I *did some grouping* **(!!)** - what I think was the problem in your code.

So my presentation containts *four slides*, each of them contains of

- one textbox
- a group with two textboxes and
- a group of two groups of another two textboxes each.

*(see screenshot of my demo file below)*

**Presentation file**
[image: PPTX File with my demo shapes/slides]

In my code I check whether the *current shape is a grouped element* or not. In this case I call my methode recursivley. Otherelse I check *if there is a textFrame* and set the according font .

**Add-In Code**

```
private void btnCalibrifyText_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        PowerPoint.SlideRange ppslr = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange;
        int slidecount = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i <= slidecount; i++)
        {
            ppApp.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides.Range(i).Select();
            ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(i).Shapes.SelectAll();
            PowerPoint.ShapeRange ppshr = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange;

            // new version
            foreach (PowerPoint.Shape shape in ppshr)
            {
                changeFont(shape);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
    catch (COMException comEx)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("COMException: " + comEx.Message + comEx.StackTrace);
        MessageBox.Show(comEx.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void changeFont(PowerPoint.Shape shape)
{
    if (shape.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoGroup)
    {
        foreach (PowerPoint.Shape childShape in shape.GroupItems)
        {
            changeFont(childShape);
        }
    }
    else if (shape.HasTextFrame == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
    {
        if (shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text != "")
        {
            var text1 = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
            text1.Font.Name = "Calibri Light";
        }
    }
}
```

Worked for me. Hope it does the trick for you too.

Comment: I also have a doubt where im trying to save multiple slides but it doesnt save my template that exist. can u help me with that

Comment: I'd like to, could you please post a new answer - link it to me - and I'll have a look into

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719767/retain-the-source-template-when-saving-slides-in-ppt

Answer (score 0):

In C#, indexes are 0-based (opposed to VB/VBA for example, which are 1-based). That makes this line fail:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= slidecount; i++)
```

It should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < slidecount; i++)
```

(You make the same mistake later on)

Comment: if i use index starting with 0 it will give an error with this line as it wont find slide range of ppApp.ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides.Range(i).Select();   it gives me error on   var text = ppshr[i].ToString(); statement

Comment: You seem to be right, [`Slides`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff746710.aspx) is 1-based... I wonder if `ShapeRange` is too...

Comment: @test: No, that one seems to be 0-based as far as I can tell.

Comment: All collections in PPT are 1-based.