# Retain the source template when saving slides in ppt

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I am trying to save selected slide so it doesnt retain my source template. how do i retain the existing template while i save the slides

```
   private void SaveSelectedSlide_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            PowerPoint.SlideRange ppslr = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange;
            string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            var temporaryPresentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Presentations.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = ppApp.ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

            for (int i = 1; i <= ppslr.Count; i++)
            {
                var sourceSlide = ppslr[i];
                sourceSlide.Copy();

                var design = sourceSlide.Design;
                temporaryPresentation.Slides.Paste();


            }

            temporaryPresentation.SaveAs("Temporary", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

            temporaryPresentation.Close();

        }
        catch (COMException Ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Some problem" + Ex.Message + Ex.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show("PLease enter text ");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the presentation changed when you call the [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746389(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Presentation class?

Comment: This code works pretty fine when I tested it. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: when the slides get saved the blank template are used. if we use some template it wont select that template. it juzt copies all shapes to destination. without source template.

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz  did u find any solution to this....

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev yes we are creating another temporary presentation and copying all the source file data to that temporary presentation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673502/add-new-slide-command-that-exists-in-home-menu-and-add-it-in-addin-ribbon-in-c-s

Comment: also if u guys could help me out with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got what you want. When pasting the new slide, *save the new* **SlideRange**. Afterwards *assign* the *design* of the **source slide**.

```
PowerPoint.Application ppApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
PowerPoint.SlideRange ppslr = ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange;
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
var temporaryPresentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Presentations.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.CustomLayout customLayout = ppApp.ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutText];

for (int i = 1; i <= ppslr.Count; i++)
{
    var sourceSlide = ppslr[i];
    sourceSlide.Copy();

    var design = sourceSlide.Design;                    
    SlideRange sr = temporaryPresentation.Slides.Paste(); // get newly created slideRange
    sr.Design = sourceSlide.Design; // manually set design
}
temporaryPresentation.SaveAs("Temporary", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
temporaryPresentation.Close();
```

It worked for me. Please let me know if this is the expected behaviour!

Comment: this didnt work for me. all the shapes are saved but not their templates . also i have a nother doubt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935838/add-shape-from-a-ppt-slide-within-a-project-to-your-current-open-slide

Comment: could you  please upload your ppt(x) file so I could make some test on the original file?

Comment: use any public share platform or just send it to me by mail franz.pilgerstorfer@pundt.at

Comment: no that we save this ppt. It gets save in document by default i want a dialog box where i can select location to  save this.

Comment: also when i save slide the 1st slide ie slide nos 1 gets save at last and last slide gets saved 1st